# Second build of Delphi project taking much longer than first build

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-10.3-rio, slowdown

We have a project that after opening the project, and doing the first build, it takes a litte less than one minute.
But if we do another build right after it takes three and a half minutes.
If I close the project and reopen it, the first build again takes less than one minute, and again the next build takes three and a half minutes

I have found through googling that other have had similar problems but that has been on way older versions of Delphi.
We are using Delphi 10.3.3, but the same issue was also present at least in Delphi 10.2.

I found that some claimed the reason was the "compiler unit cache", and that clearing this would fix the problem. Apparently in older versions of Delphi at least there was a hidden menu item on the project menu "Clear unit cache".

Anyone experiencing the same, and know how to fix it?

Comment: I suggest to install [Delphi IDE Fix Pack](https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/).

Comment: I allready have both Ide Fix Pack and DDevextensions installed. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Which size of project do you have and which computer configuration? I ask because on my computer, compiling and linking 400K lines of code into 262 units takes only 6 seconds.

Comment: Almost 6 million lines of code including thirty party code.
I have no problem with the first Build taking almost a minute. Its the second build taking than long that so annoying. Should be possible to take the same amount of time as the first Build.

Comment: What if you double the amount of RAM?

Comment: I have 16 GB of RAM, and the amount of RAM doesn't change between build 1 and 2 ;-)

Comment: You don't know if you don't try. I suspect building such a large project will allocate lots of cached resources that will be reused at the (possible) gain/cost of performance.

Comment: I always suspected some kind of cashe being the cause, thats why I mentioned the "Clear unit cache" menu item.
I have now enabled this menuitem via installing a packaged found here:
https://github.com/evandroamparo/delphi-hacks

If i click the "Clear unit cache" menu item before each build, every build takes abut the same time. 
So at least we now have a workaround and a cause of the problem.